# How to perform strict integer optimization in Python or C++?

Tags: python, c++, optimization, integer

I have a strict integer optimization problem. I cannot cannot have the optimization code make a guess that is a float. All function calls must be integers.

For example, I want to minimize the following function:

```
def func(x, y):
    return x ** 2 - y * 2
```

where x [image: x \in {}] {2, 3, ..., 10} and y [image: x \in {}] {-10, -9, ..., -2}.

By inspection, the solution here is x = 2 and y = -2. No guesses by the optimizer function can be floats. I cannot afford to have the algorithm calculate all possible values, because the function call takes time. It needs to be some kind of branching procedure that finds the solution in a reasonable number of function calls. Does an algorithm like this exist?

I am writing this in python. However, if there is a C++ version of the algorithm I wouldn't mind writing a wrapper and calling it from Python. Although, the easiest solution would be to already have it callable from Python.

Comment: If it's a polynomial function you are trying to optimize, gradient descent tends to perform well in those types of problems. If it's something more complex, it really depends on the problem, I've always had good experiences with particle swarms in real optimization, which is essentially the same as integer optimization.

Comment: What are the characteristics of the function? (contiguous, derivative, ...)

Comment: @nick Its continuous through the squares. Ie. if x and y are both the same number, that is a continuous. Now that I think about it, if I were to calculate the matrix, it would be a symmetric matrix.

Comment: @Jarod42 It is a contiguous solution I believe. The actual function is different than this minimal. The actual function will return the same values for x = 2 y = 10 and x = 10 y = 2.

Comment: Have you looked at simplex? It sounds like that might work for your problem.

Comment: So "integer quadratic programming"? Wikipedia lists some software.

Comment: @nick Yeah I'd like a simplex procedure, but the only simplex procedures I am familiar with is going to use floats as guesses

Comment: It should still work if you just round the guess to the nearest integer. I.e. if it says the next point to try is <1.3764, 0.21452> you just try <1,0>. You could also be smart and try rounding both ways to see which is better.

Comment: @nick Okay I think I should look into specifying the initial simplex guesses.